# How to get custom tags that was set in Sentry

Tags: tags, sentry

I'm using [Sentry](https://sentry.io) to track errors on my app and I [set custom tags](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/enriching-events/tags/) when I initialize Sentry.

```js
Sentry.setTag('custom', 'custom tag value');
```

Later on in the app, I need this custom tag value, is there a way for me to retrieve it back? I've tried `Sentry.getTag('custom')` and it doesn't work. I've been looking at their documentation and I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get the tag once you set it.

When you look at the source code or type declaration for setTag function, the setTag function returns the instance of Scope class. In the Scope class, tags property is protected and there is no method such as getTag for retrieving tag key:value pair value.